# Correct way to instantiate a class member of template class with paramter

Tags: c++, class, templates, instantiation

I have a template class with an instantiation parameter.
I have another class that has a member parameter of that class.

The follow does not compile because it says instantiation method is deleted...

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyTClass<AClass> tclass;
}
```

The following works but I am not sure if it is the correct way...

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyTClass<AClass> tclass = MyTClass<AClass>(1234);
}
```

It seems the member paramter is instantiated but is it tidied up on owner class destruction?

I wish to avoid new and delete if I can to keep my code tidy so I am thinking I wish to take advantance of member parameter instantiation on class instantiation. As I have added explicit instantiation, do I need to fall back to new and delete to ensure it is destructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything extra here. The destructor of `MyClass` invokes the destructor of all members, regardless of how they were originally constructed.

(This is true even if the member is a pointer. But the destructor of a pointer does nothing, which is why you'd need a `delete` call to destruct and free *the thing it points to*.)